# Muon Discover fails to find Wine

Tags: package-management, 15.04, wine, kubuntu, muon-package-manager

Well, this is a beginners question. I am using my first personal Linux installation running Kubuntu 15.04.

There have been several software packages I couldn't find using Muon discover. In most cases I used the command line and/or installed some third-party source to solve the problem.

However today I tried to install Wine... and Muon Discover couldn't find it. I can't believe that such a popular application is not available through the default sources.

Should Muon Discover find Wine? If yes... what could be the problem? Why is Muon unable to find Wine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer by myself, by chance.

Muon discover has an important option in its menu. It is called "Show technical packages" which is available in the popup options menu (the one with a wand like icon in the top right corner of the window).
To make it even more counter-intuitive... the option menu icon is only visible if you have already filtered out some packages by entering a search phrase.

Wine obviously is considered such a "technical package". So setting the checkbox shows wine... and a lot of other stuff.

I wonder if this is the way it should behave.